Need help understanding how certain mathemetical statements across the landscape can seemingly contradict (e.g. Cantor-Hume vs Euclid)
Here are the main components to my understanding on this issue:

Almost all of math can be given in a foundation of set theory
Different math can seemingly contradict, e.g. in Euclidean geometry parallel lines never meet but they can in other geometries
Those branches contradicting is okay because neither branch contradicts with the foundational theory. The branches at are "high levels", abstracted from the base a bit. These allow for the  foundational theory to be agnostic to the higher level statement about parallel lines and its negation.

So far I can understand and swallow that two geometries can contradict.
But what if one of the statements is at/close to the foundational level? E.g. the Cantor-Hume principle that a "set is infinite if and only if it is equivalent to one of its proper subsets". Now I don't know exactly how close to the base axioms of ZFC the CHP is, but it is about sets, and we've been told the rest of math can be put in terms of sets/set theory. Then, further removed are mathematical concepts like measure. Measure, I've been told, makes use of Euclid's principle--the whole is greater than the part. Measure theory can be founded in ZFC set theory. But Euclid's principle, unlike before, seemingly can't be agnostic with the CHP. It's at a higher level, but contradicts with a statement at a lower level (seemingly). They conflict because an infinte set (a whole) is not greater than its proper subset (a part). This conflict I can't explain as in the first case.
So what's going on? Does Euclid's Principle contract the CHP like Euclidean geometry contradicts other geometry? Perhaps they don't contradict because the language of the two is sufficiently vague? And if they do conflict, how can we countenance that contradiction in the CHP case where the conflict seems to cut vertically across math instead of horizontally?
I'm asking here because I feel like I'm not yet capable of asking this in purely mathematical terms, and that there is potentially a philosophical side regardless.

Saying two “branches” contradict is bad terminology. Those “branches” explicitly work under different axioms – they assume different things. Once this is understood, they don’t even seem to contradict. I can dislike cucumbers in a sandwich but like them in a salad without being in contradiction; they are two different contexts.

@JustSomeOldMan  When both are explained in terms of ZFC, which axioms differ?

@J Kusin As an explicit example, the theory of algebraic semigroups assumes associativity but not divisibility, whereas the theory of algebraic quasigroups assumes divisibility but not associativity.

@JustSomeOldMan Okay yes I've taken abstract algebra so I understand that. But, when working under the setting of ZFC being a foundation for much of math, including abstract algebra, aren't the set theory axioms remaining the same when switching between those algebraic structures?

Yes, of course. I don't know how to answer the question because "Euclid's principle" is not phrased mathematically.

This question belongs in the math group, but to get a good response, you should drop the stuff about contradictions. As @JustSomeOldMan points out, there aren't any contradictions, only different axioms. Also, I'd drop the word "equivalent" and use "there is a bijection". The answer involves the fact that just because there is a bijection between two sets of points that doesn't mean the points have the same geometric measure.

@DavidGudeman Those are good editing critiques. Yes two geometries have different "high level" axioms ergo maybe my language is a bit sloppy there, but aren't they both built from the same set theory axioms at a lower level, only diverging in axioms past a certain point?

Different sets of axioms can be interpreted in the same set theory. This is the entire subject of model theory.

They can "contradict" due to equivocation. "Parallel lines" of one geometry are not those of another, in base terms of set theory. And you can do this at any level of 'fundamentality'. You can construct objects in ZFC and a relation on them so that they satisfy axioms of alternative set theories, and then call them "sets" and the relation "∈" to get a 'contradiction'. This is even simpler with measure, it is no cardinality even superficially (and does not satisfy Euclid's axiom anyway due to measure 0 sets). This is not about 'fundamentality', it is about relativism of interpretations.

Set theory makes a difference between "inclusion" (proper inclusion reflects Euclid's common notion) and "cardinality" based on the concept of bijection, that formalize the way to apply the "counting" procedure to every set, also the infinite ones.

@Conifold Is that universally appreciated? If the gradations are that fine, are we in danger of saying Euclid's geometry and Hilbert's Euclidean geometry speak of different mathematical objects? Do we want that? Maybe there's a more stark example where we really wouldn't want to say the mathematical objects change across syntactic changes. My hesitation is if it's too fine, then there are infinite notions of lines for that matter, if there are infinite set theories. This would be like infinite "rednesses" which seems undesirable as universals would be extremely high in number.

We can say that Euclid's geometry and Hilbert's Euclidean geometry speak of the same objects or of different objects. Set theory does not care how we interpret models constructed in it, it is just a language. Of course, if one is a platonist, they can say that base sets are really sets, base ∈ is really elementhood and base axioms are truths of the platonic realm. But you still will not get contradictions just because models of something else constructed as compound objects from true sets satisfy different axioms, even if you call those objects "sets".

Based on the comments/answer(s) I found https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4773310/890429 which helps me see how "extensions" consistent with the base ZFC axioms can be not isomorphic amongst each other. And I think I see why it's proper to call them not isomorphic rater than contradictory because contradiction usually happens at the most fundamental layer.

Cantor-Hume principle is worded in the terms of cardinality: "set is infinite if and only if it has equal cardinality to one of its proper subsets". If you see it phrased in a different way, it is not precise.
What this phrase means in lay words is that a set is infinite if one can make a one-to-one correspondence between the set and one of its proper subets.
The Euclid's principle is phrased using numerosity, which is a generalization of the concept of measure. It says that the numerosity of a proper subset is less than the numerosity of the whole set. It defines infinite set as one which has numerosity greater than any natural number.
The both definitions of infinite sets, via numerosity or cardinality, coincide. A set, infinite in one sense is also infinite in the other sense.
Provided certain equivalence rules, numerosities of subsets of  have total order and can be represented as elements of , a subset of surreal numbers. Numerosities of countable sets can be represented as elements of , which is the set of so-called, countable surreals.
Numerosities of some unbounded sets can change under shift, for instance, the numerosity of non-negative integers is greater than numerosity of positive integers by 1.They also depend on the metric or order of the space, so they can be defined differently on subsets of other spaces than .
Numerosity is a more precise notion of the set's size, as two sets with the same cardinality can have different numerosities, but two sets with the same numerosities inevitably have the same cardinality. If cardinality of one set is greater than the cardinality of another set, then its numerosity is also greater.
